# Leitura de entrada dinâmica em C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, http-request

Estou desenvolvendo uma solução em Winforms C# que recebe um arquivo de texto via rede, via `HttpWebRequest`:

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(conexao + "/piece.txt");
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10; 
            var sp = request.ServicePoint;
            var prop = sp.GetType().GetProperty("HttpBehaviour", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            prop.SetValue(sp, (byte)0, null);
```

E a leitura é feita por `StreamReader`:

```
 StreamReader stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
              stream.ReadTimeout = 8600000; //Para Evitar o timeout
```

Esse arquivo é gerado por uma balança de esteira(cada peso que passa por ela gera uma linha no arquivo texto `piece.txt`) e devido a isso o arquivo não tem definição de tamanho nem de `EOF`. O meu problema acontece quando nessa esteira não esta passando peso e meu sistema esta tentando ler o arquivo, que é feito desta forma:

```
while ((buffer = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{....
```

Quando o Sistema passa 1 minuto sem receber texto essa linha de código estoura um erro:

> Não é possível ler os dados da conexão de transporte: Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto.

Já tentei usar o `reader.Peek()`, porém o mesmo erro acontece.

Preciso de uma solução que não estoure esse erro caso não tenha texto, ou seja, ela verifique que esta vazio e espere até aparecer uma linha(sem estourar `timeout` da operação).

Alguma ideia que possa me ajudar?

Um leitor dinâmico talvez?

Comment: Pergunta equivalente na comunidade inglesa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525364/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-website-in-c-sharp